# Kotlin Gradle build is not running

Tags: gradle, kotlin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a Spring Boot application backed with Kotlin as the language, and Gradle as the build system. So basically I'm trying to build a fat jar out of the application source and dependencies, which can be run using Java command line tool.

Gradle build script:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: "kotlin-spring"
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'


group 'myapp'
version '1.0'

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21' // Required for Kotlin integration
    ext.spring_boot_version = '1.5.4.RELEASE'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:$kotlin_version" // See https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#kotlin-spring-compiler-plugin
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$spring_boot_version"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin/'
    test.java.srcDirs += 'src/test/kotlin/'
}


jar {
    zip64 true
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'app.main.ApplicationKt'
    }
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
}


sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre8:$kotlin_version"
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    compile group: 'com.typesafe', name: 'config', version: '1.3.2'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-spring-boot-starter', version: '2.20.2'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-redis', version: '2.0.0.RELEASE'

    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-quartz2', version: '2.20.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-http4', version: '2.20.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-docker', version: '2.20.2'
    compile group: 'org.apache.camel', name: 'camel-aws', version: '2.20.2'

    compile group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.4.0'
    compile group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '2.9.0'
    compile group: 'joda-time', name: 'joda-time', version: '2.9.9'
    compile group: 'net.gpedro.integrations.slack', name: 'slack-webhook', version: '1.4.0'
    compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
    compile group: 'org.jfree', name: 'jfreechart', version: '1.5.0'

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

If I run the project using gradle command then it runs fine. But when I build the jar and try ti run it complains with the below error:-

```
Error: Could not find or load main class app.main.ApplicationKt
```

Application.kt:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath*:camel-context.xml")
@ComponentScan("app")
class Application

fun main(args:Array<String>){
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}
```

Not sure where exactly I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: Please show how your `Application.kt` file looks like?

Comment: Are you sure the `package` is specified correctly in the `Application.kt` ?

Comment: package app.main

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath*:camel-context.xml")
@ComponentScan("app")
class Application

fun main(args:Array<String>){
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)
}

Comment: @miensol yes this is what my Application.kt file looks like

Comment: What is the command you use to run the jar?

Comment: have you used `java -jar youJarFile.jar` ?

Comment: java -jar myapp.jar

Comment: If possible upload the jar file so we can inspect it.

Answer (score 0):

In `Application.kt`, you do not have a `package` declaration. From the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/packages.html):

> All the contents (such as classes and functions) of the source file are contained by the package declared. So, in the example above, the full name of `baz()` is `foo.bar.baz`, and the full name of `Goo` is `foo.bar.Goo`.
>
> If the package is not specified, the contents of such a file belong to "default" package that has no name.

You can look into the `build/classes` directory to inspect what packages the classes were compiled into.

To fix this issue, add `package app.main` to the top of the `Application.kt` file.

Answer (score 0):

for some reason I encountered the same error but my package was declared. I copied the package deleted the line and pasted, saved, reloaded the project and the application ran. I don´t have a logical explanation for this, but that is how I solved this error.